# How to customize UILabel with different Font Size and Color with multiple Variables together

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicolor, uifont

I'm trying to put **3 variables in the same UILabel to make emphasis on the second word.**

With one variable it work's fine. (Option 1)

```
    //Option 1 That work with one variable
    labelBoldAnswer.attributedText = secondWordBoldRed
```

**THE RESULT 1 IS**: Bold and Red

[image]

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldOriginal : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelBoldAnswer   : UILabel!

@IBAction func ButtonBold(sender: AnyObject) {

    var firstWord   = "First Word"
    var thirdWord   = "Third Word"

    var attrs      = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
    var secondWordBoldRed = NSMutableAttributedString (string:textFieldOriginal.text, attributes: attrs)

    //Option 1 That work with one variable
    labelBoldAnswer.attributedText = secondWordBoldRed

    //Option 2 That work partialy
    //labelBoldAnswer.text = ("\(firstWord), \(secondWordBoldRed), \(thirdWord)")
```

}

**SECOND TRY**

With three variables, it show's all the text with code instead of showing bigger text and red in the center of the First and Third word. (Option 2)

```
//Option 2 That work partialy
    labelBoldAnswer.text = ("\(firstWord), \(secondWordBoldRed), \(thirdWord)")
```

**THE RESULT 2 IS NOT PERFECT**:

[image]

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldOriginal : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelBoldAnswer   : UILabel!

@IBAction func ButtonBold(sender: AnyObject) {

    var firstWord   = "First Word"
    var thirdWord   = "Third Word"

    var attrs      = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
    var secondWordBoldRed = NSMutableAttributedString (string:textFieldOriginal.text, attributes: attrs)

    //Option 1 That work with one variable
    //labelBoldAnswer.attributedText = secondWordBoldRed

    //Option 2 That work partialy
    labelBoldAnswer.text = ("\(firstWord), \(secondWordBoldRed), \(thirdWord)")
```

}

Thank's  for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You can either build the attributed string up, adding attributes to the different parts as you go:

```
    let firstWord   = "First Word"
    let secondWord = "Insert Text"
    let attrs      = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
    let thirdWord   = "Third Word"
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:firstWord)
    attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: secondWord, attributes: attrs))
    attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: thirdWord))
    textField.attributedText = attributedText
```

Or create the thing, then add an attribute to the range.  This is somewhat complicated by the fact that NSAttributedString use NSRange, and Swift String use `Range<String.index>`.

```
    let firstWord   = "First Word"
    let secondWord = "Insert Text"
    let thirdWord   = "Third Word"
    let comboWord = firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:comboWord)
    let attrs      = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
    let range = NSString(string: comboWord).rangeOfString(secondWord)
    attributedText.addAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    textField.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: I like the second one with .rangeOfString but the only thing is missing is the code to see the result in the UILabel. I know it start with: labelBoldAnswer.text =

Comment: `labelBoldAnswer.text = attributedText`

Comment: The message that came is: "NSMutableAttributedString is not a sub type of NSString". I've added:  labelBoldAnswer.text = attributedText.mutableString.  That way, it work but with no bold  and no red color caracters. Have an idea?

Comment: @ShakeMan should be `labelBoldAnswer.attributedText = attributedText`

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following:

```
let attrsA = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(10)]
var a = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"hello", attributes:attrsA)
let attrsB =  [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
let b = NSAttributedString(string:"world", attributes:attrsB)
a.appendAttributedString(b)
```

which will create a string `a` that has multiple attributes mixed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to construct an attributed string with all the variable values, and proper styling in the proper ranges. There are multiple solutions to this, but I would recommend you to have a look at NSMutableAttributedString:

1. create your "parts" exactly as you did for secondWordBoldRed
2. combine them using -[NSMutableAttributedString appendAttributedString:]
3. set labelBoldAnswer.attributedText to the NSMutableAttributedString